# Как с помощью Python можно анализировать логи

Tags: python, логирование

У меня есть лог с запросами 400mb. Какие библиотеки/средства могут мне помочь в анализе такого лога в Python? Анализ заключается в поиске запросов связанные с определенной темой и определение классификации запроса. Результат анализа по возможности лучше записать.

Шаблон выглядит таким образом: timestamp    datetime    device  numdoc  region  request urls

```
1520974801  2018-03-14 00:00    touch   171673301   16  https://yandex.ru/search/?text=сергей из ярославля дом 2?&flag=yMvu3235 http://dom2.tw/uchastniki/sergey-ermakov.html;http://dom2.ru/heroes/bivshie?page=1;https://dom2.show/uchastniki/ekaterina-balakina.html
```

Comment: Помочь могут совершенно разные библиотеки. Зависит от того, как именно хочется анализировать.

Comment: не зная подробностей трудно дать толковый совет. Посмотрите: pandas, sklearn, tensorflow, keras

Comment: grep ваш лучший помощник

Comment: Речь о машинном обучении или о простом поиске подстрок?

Comment: Скорее о простом поиске